# Copy Oracle table to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, linked-server, openquery

I need to copy data from a linked server Oracle table and append to SQL Server table in a regular time interval.

Without using SSIS or any external etl, can this be done by using open query? I have read in forums that the table has to be exported to csv and then imported back again into SQL Server . Is there an alternative as this will be continuous process  ?

Comment: *"can this be done by using open query?"* provided you can easily identify unique rows with a unique key yes. If you are also expecting to `UPDATE` existing rows as well, then it'll be really beneficial if you have the equivalent of SQL Server's `ROWVERSION` on the Oracle instance, so you can tell *what* rows has been updated. Though I doubt that any such process will be particularly efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly. As long as you've configured the Linked Server properly within SQL Server, and your user account has the right permissions in Oracle, getting and sending data between the two is fairly trivial.

Selecting data from Oracle into SQL Server:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#myTemp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #myTemp

SELECT * 
INTO #myTemp
FROM OPENQUERY(MyLinkedServer, 'SELECT col1, col2 
                                FROM OracleTableName 
                                WHERE SomeColumn = ''Human Resources''')
```

Inserting data from SQL Server into Oracle:

```
-- note: please make sure you have your columns in the exact same order!
INSERT INTO OPENQUERY(MyLinkedServer, 'SELECT col1 
                                       FROM OracleTableName ') 
SELECT myPK 
FROM AdventureWorks2014.dbo.SomeTable
```

And you can even drop or recreate a table in Oracle from SQL Server, and run stored procedures.

To create a linked server, I use the below script and [these settings](https://pasteboard.co/JDhUeW9.png):

```
-- make sure you have Oracle drivers on your SQL Server, and an up-to-date TNSNames.ora file
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'MyLinkedServer', @srvproduct=N'Oracle', @provider=N'OraOLEDB.Oracle', @datasrc=N'TNS_NAME_HERE' 

-- disable any logins not explicitly mapped
EXEC master.dbo.sp_droplinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname = N'MyLinkedServer', @locallogin = NULL 

-- login mapping between SQL Server user and their appropriate Oracle account
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'MyLinkedServer',@useself=N'False',@locallogin=N'domain\username',@rmtuser=N'ORACLE_USERNAME',@rmtpassword='ORACLE_PASSWORD'
-- add a mapping for your SQL Agent account if these will run under jobs, 
-- and your SQL Engine account if you still get errors on things that are automated, 
-- unless those automated jobs are explicitly running under user accounts
```

Honestly, the hardest part is making sure you get Oracle drivers installed right on the SQL Server. After that, it's very straightforward.

Comment: Thank you very much . This helps . Little off topic question here , I have a linked server configured on sql server to connect to oracle but I have been provided separate credentials to connect to the linked oracle server . Is there a way to map or configure the credentials in the query or in the sql server instance ?

Comment: That is precisely what the last query does, @RData. Maps your (or any) SQL account to the explicit Oracle credentials you are to connect under.